# How to position a button (or any GUI element) in a JavaFX scene?

Tags: user-interface, button, javafx, position, fxml

I am trying to put a JavaFX button in a specific place (specific coordinates) on a UI, but nothing is working. I'm guessing that there is a method that is used for this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can use pane. setLayoutX() and setLayoutY().

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Tester extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    Pane root = new Pane();
    btn.setLayoutX(250);
    btn.setLayoutY(220);
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `layoutX` and `layoutY`

```
<Button text="Button" layoutX="50" layoutY="100" />
```

In FXML, you can use the [`layoutX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty) and [`layoutY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutYProperty) properties that are inherited from [`javafx.scene.Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).

According to the [JavaFX Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> **layoutX**
>
> Defines the x coordinate of the translation that is added to this Node's transform for the purpose of layout.
>
> **layoutY**
>
> Defines the y coordinate of the translation that is added to this Node's transform for the purpose of layout.

The example below results in a window in which a [`Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) element is positioned with an x-coordinate of `50` and a y-coordinate of `100`.

**sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<Scene>
  <Pane prefWidth="300" prefHeight="300">
    <!-- Button Positioned Using layoutX and layoutY -->
    <Button text="Button" layoutX="50" layoutY="100" />
  </Pane>
</Scene>
```

**Main.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Window Title");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

> **Note:** You can also use the [`setLayoutX()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) and [`setLayoutY()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutY-double-) methods to set the values of the [`layoutX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty) and [`layoutY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutYProperty) properties dynamically in the controller, rather than through the markup. Additionally, you can use the [`layoutX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty) and [`layoutY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutYProperty) tags (i.e. `<layoutX>` and `<layoutY>`) within the UI element tag to set the x-coordinates and y-coordinates inside of the FXML markup as an alternative to using attributes.